# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: xml

found an exception 101 in getting data from XML file:XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/zaid/Desktop/xml/cd_catalog.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to request a resource through your local machine, that's a cross reference. You need to access to this resource trough your HTTP server to get access to it.