# XMLHttpRequest Cannot Load https://[website].com Cross Origin Requests are not supported

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

I ran my JavaScript file with `phantomjs --web-security=no myfile.js` successfully in my MacBook (with macOS), but fail to run it on Ubuntu, where it give out this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest Cannot Load https://[website].com Cross Origin
Requests are not supported
```

I find my problem is different from questions below

1. [XMLHttpRequest cannot load Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194518/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http)
2. [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.[website].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

For the first one, my error message is simply '**not supported**', but not tell my 'only supported for HTTP' (though I send request to a HTTPS url).
For the second one, my error message doesn't require the '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header.

I tried `--debug=true` option for PhantomJS, and it turned out that when running within Ubuntu, the PhantomJS silently dropping cookies.

Under my circumstance, could any one tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What is the actual parent request? The error is for sub request, maybe the protocol of parent and child requests are different.

Comment: @ThanNgoHoai My request is simply `var request = new XMLHttpRequest()` and then `request.open('GET','my URL',false); request.sent()`. I don't know what is a sub request.

Comment: So your 'my URL' should be the same protocol and server name with the current page.

Comment: Yes, I reckon that they are the same, otherwise it can't runs in my macOS without this error.

Comment: I tried `--debug=true` option in phantomjs. It turned out that when running within Ubuntu, the PhantomJS silently dropping cookies. I am afraid its the trigger of this error?

Answer (score 0):

phantomjs seems to have an option which allows to make XMLHttpRequests from local files to a http server: **--local-to-remote-url-access**

For reference: http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html